# Android Run a service to capture call voice up-link and down-link from device

Tags: android

I am trying to write a background service which runs when a call is connected (but calling is done by native calling app) capture it's voice up-link and down-link audio stream. After capturing send it to server.

Once call ended I need to shutdown the service. How this can be achievable? Should I make a system app? Or any other way. This is just a exploration not an application to be deployed.